# ¿Se puede acceder a un DbContext desde otro proyecto de la misma solución?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Tengo un proyecto en el que uso EEFF para crear la db, con sus tablas y usarlas. Mi pregunta es, tengo forma de acceder a esa misma base desde otro proyecto, usando EEFF?

Calculo que referenciando al DbContext del proyecto que crea la base.

Estoy usando 2 proyectos web con ASP.NET Core 3.0

Comment: Ya lo intentaste?

Comment: Para mi la mejor opcion es hacer una Api que te devuelva los resultados, y lo vas llamando segun necesites.

Comment: Podes hacer un proyecto que sea la capa de datos, y luego lo llamas desde cualquier proyecto

Comment: lo había intentado antes de crear la pregunta, y no me dejaba. pero después si me dejo, hacer un "using Proyecto1.Data" y lo mismo para Models. no se si cuando lo termine publicando va a funcionar, espero que si. 
También cree la conexión con la DB.
Gracias por su tiempo.